# Spring Data JPA Repository function does not work in Test

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have a question regarding Spring Data JPA.
To make it as simple as possible I made up a very simple example.

We have the TestUser, that can have a FavouriteColor, but his favouriteColor can also be null.

TestUser.kt

```
@Entity
class TestUser(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "TestUserId")
    var userId: Long,
    @Column(name = "Name")
    var name: String,
    @Column(name = "FavouriteColorId")
    var favouriteColorId: Long? = null,
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(
        name = "FavouriteColorId",
        referencedColumnName = "FavouriteColorId",
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false,
        nullable = true
    )
    var favouriteColor: FavouriteColor? = null
)
```

FavouriteColor.kt

```
@Entity
class FavouriteColor(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "FavouriteColorId")
    var favouriteColorId: Long,
    @Column(name = "ColorCode")
    var colorCode: String
)
```

When I search for the users that have a favourite Color by `findTestUsersByFavouriteColorNotNull()`, the size of the result is 0. Even if there is an User that has a favourite color. And when I use `findAll()` and then apply the filter, the result is correct.

StackOverflowTest.kt

```
@SpringBootTest
@Transactional
class StackOverflowTest {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var testUserRepository: TestUserRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var favouriteColorRepository: FavouriteColorRepository

    @Test
    fun testFilter() {
        val favouriteColor = FavouriteColor(favouriteColorId = 0L, colorCode = "#000000")
        favouriteColorRepository.save(favouriteColor)

        val user = testUserRepository.save(TestUser(userId = 0L, name = "Testuser"))
        user.favouriteColor = favouriteColor
        testUserRepository.save(user)

        val usersWithColor1 = testUserRepository.findAll().filter { it.favouriteColor != null }
        assert(usersWithColor1.size == 1) // This assertion is correct

        val usersWithColor2 = testUserRepository.findTestUsersByFavouriteColorIdIsNotNull()
        assert(usersWithColor2.size == 1) // This assertion fails

        val usersWithColor3 = testUserRepository.findTestUsersByFavouriteColorIsNotNull()
        assert(usersWithColor3.size == 1) // This assertion fails

    }
}
```

***Update:***
I added the Repository function `findTestUsersByFavouriteColorIdNotNull()` but it also does not work

***Update2:***
I updated the functions to `findTestUsersByFavouriteColorIdIsNotNull` and `findTestUsersByFavouriteColorIsNotNull`, but the assertions are still failing

Can somebody explain me, why the `findTestUsersByFavouriteColorNotNull()` does not work ? And is there some way to get this function working in the tests?
Thanks :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `findTestUsersByFavouriteColorIdNotNull` ?

Comment: No sadly this doesn't work either, I updated the question

Comment: You're missing the therm `is` which want make it compare to a param. It should be `...IdIsNotNull()`. And hopefully your Repo inherites the correct one for JPA interactions. Otherwise JPA won't autogenerate functionality.

Comment: I updated the functions to `findTestUsersByFavouriteColorIdIsNotNull` and `findTestUsersByFavouriteColorIsNotNull`, but the assertions are still failing

Comment: @LenglBoy `is` is optional, it should work with or without it, as stated in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods).

Answer (score 0):

I'm suspecting that happen because you have 2 variables of the same column name

```
@Column(name = "FavouriteColorId")
var favouriteColorId: Long? = null,
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(
    name = "FavouriteColorId",
    referencedColumnName = "FavouriteColorId",
    insertable = false,
    updatable = false,
    nullable = true
)
var favouriteColor: FavouriteColor? = null
```

Try removing one of the variable, and try again.